# Python. Временные ряды

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, статистика, анализ, статический-анализ

Есть данные о дневных поступлениях в кассу сети магазинов и расходах за последние три года. Есть данные об инфляции, праздникак/выходных и количестве магазинов за последние три года. Необходимо спрогнозировать движение денежных масс на полгода вперед: поступления, расходы и остаток на конец дня.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, инструмент/алгоритм/библиотеку на Python, подходящую для прогноза.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае я бы обратил внимание на следующие модули/библиотеки:

- pandas - загрузка, выгрузка, обработка табличных данных
- sklearn (scikit-learn) - препроцессинг и нормализация данных, богатый набор алгоритмов машинного обучения, несколько относительно примитивных алгоритмов нейронных сетей
- tensorflow, keras, theano, lasagne,  Blocks, Pylearn2, PyTorch, (постоянно появляется что-то новое) - нейронные сети, алгоритмы глубокого обучения, алгоритмы машинного обучения

[Пример модели `"Multivariate Time Series Forecasting with LSTMs in Keras"`](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/)

PS я бы посоветовал начинать изучение от простого (но необходимого) к сложному:

1. Pandas
2. sklearn
3. Keras (+Tensorflow)

Имеет смысл пройти несколько курсов (ещё лучше специализаций). Лично мне понравились следующие курсы:

- [Machine Learning](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning)
- [Applied Data Science with Python Specialization](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/data-science-python)
- [Deep Learning Specialization](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/deep-learning)

PS возможно где-то есть хорошие курсы на русском (я не интересовался)

Comment: В целом поддерживаю MaxU, но внесу небольшое замечание. Нейронные сети для тривиального (пусть даже с наличием сезонности) анализа временного ряда, с всего-лишь двумя переменными - мне кажется из пушки по воробьям. Вполне классическая задача. Так что Deep Learning,  tensorflow, keras, theano, lasagne, Blocks, Pylearn2, PyTorch, -  хоть и модно, но лучше оставить "на потом". А вот pandas, sklearn, numpy да matplotlib - необходимый минимум.

Comment: @passant, наверное вы правы. Я подумал, что если есть какая-то хитрая зависимость которую трудно будет распознать обычными регрессионными моделями, то нейронная сеть (например со слоем LSTM) будет лучше справляться. Но не видя данных  - это невозможно сказать наверняка...